# Передать свою функцию в PHPThreads

Tags: php

Приветствую, на примере https://github.com/wielski/PHPThreads/blob/master/demos/demo3.php sleep отлично работает. Вопрос как я могу использовать там свою функцию (она работает с бд и обновляет информацию) Обычный вызов идет так:

```
echo the_server();
```

Выводит результат в виде строки с цифрами.
Как мне the_server() использовать вместо sleep? Или может кто подскажет идею лучше?

Comment: Что сейчас не устраивает? Зачем менять?

Comment: @titov_andrei на примере в демо указан sleep но мне то нужно свою функцию передать. а